# Play Framework Ebean query retreival

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I want to show previous 5 transactions of the currently signed in user in my banking app.

```
public static Model.Finder<String,Transaction> find = new Model.Finder<String,Transaction>(String.class,Transaction.class);

public static List<Transaction> fetchTransactions (String currentUser) {
    return find.where().eq("user.username",currentUser).setMaxRows(5).findList();
}
```

I also tried the Ebean.find function:

```
@Inject 
List<Transaction> list = Ebean.find(Transaction.class).fetch("transNature").fetch("amount").where().eq("user.username",User.findByEmail(request().username()).username).findList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get last 5 transactions, then you have to include order by respective column, say transactionDate by descending order. Otherwise Ebean by default, fetch rows order by id in ascending order. So you will always get first 5 rows from your transaction table.

Try this,

```
public static List<Transaction> fetchTransactions(String currentUser) {
  return find.where().eq("user.username",currentUser).orderBy("transactionDate desc").setMaxRows(5).findList();
}
```